# How to create an inner class where only the outer class can access the constructor, but the rest is visible everywhere?

Tags: kotlin

I originally wanted to create a class that can abort instantiation in constructor, but according to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9965381/10645087) I should instead use a Factory class. But now I want to prevent anyone except the factory class from creating an object of class "Inner" while giving access to the methods of the inner class to everyone.

I have already tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17190867/10645087).

```
import java.util.Date

object InnerFactory {

    class Inner private constructor(startDate: Date? = null, endDate: Date? = null) {
        fun getTimeDifference(): Long? {
            //calculates time difference but doesn't matter to this example
        }
    }

    fun createInnerObject(startDate: Date? = null, endDate: Date? = null): Inner? {
        if (startDate != null && endDate != null && !endDate.after(startDate)) {
            return null
        }

        return Inner(startDate, endDate)
    }

}
```

I would use it like the following:

```
val date1 = Date(1547600000)
val date2 = Date(1547600600)
val inner = InnerFactory.createInnerObject(date1, date2) //should return an instance
val invalidInner = InnerFactory.createInnerObject(date2, date1) //should not return an instance because the "endDate" is before "startDate"
val difference = inner?.getTimeDifference()
```

It says "cannot access '<init>': it is private in 'Inner'" when hovering over my usage of the constructor in the "createInnerObject" function.

Comment: Just a note: Kotlin differentiates between "inner" and "nested" classes. Your `Inner` class is actually a nested class. An actual inner class is defined with the `inner` keyword. The difference is that an inner class carries a reference to an object of the outer class. You can read more about it here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you could do:

- introduce an `interface Inner` with all the necessary functions that should be exposed
- make all the class(es) `private` and implement that interface

Sample:

```
object InnerFactory {

  interface Inner {
    fun getTimeDifference(): Long?
  }

  private class InnerImpl(startDate: Date? = null, endDate: Date? = null) : Inner {
    override fun getTimeDifference(): Long? = TODO("some implementation")
  }


  fun createInnerObject(startDate: Date? = null, endDate: Date? = null): Inner? {
    if (startDate != null && endDate != null && !endDate.after(startDate)) {
      return null
    }
    return InnerImpl(startDate, endDate) // InnerImpl accessible from here but not from outside of InnerFactory...
  }
}
```

Now you can't access `InnerImpl` from outside anymore, but still have all the necessary functions available:

```
// the following all work as it deals with the interface
val inner = InnerFactory.createInnerObject(date1, date2) //should return an instance
val invalidInner = InnerFactory.createInnerObject(date2, date1) //should not return an instance because the "endDate" is before "startDate"
val difference = inner?.getTimeDifference()

// the following will not compile:
InnerImpl()
```

Comment: good idea! +1 the only drawback is that you first need to define properties / functions in the interface and then have to override it in InnerImpl which is a little redundant.

Comment: yes, that's true... but I think it's common to use an `interface` for such constructs...

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, `private` members of Kotlin inner classes are not accessible from the outer instance:

> `private` means visible inside this class only
>   <sub>[Kotlin reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/) / [Visibility modifiers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html)</sub>

However, Java is not this restrictive with its visibility modifiers:

> access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level type ([§7.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6)) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor. 
>   <sub>[Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/) / [§6 Names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html) / [§6.6 Access Control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6) / [§6.6.1 Determining Accessibility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1)</sub>

This is one of the only (annoying) cases I have found where Kotlin's rules make a common Java pattern impossible.

The only workarounds (*if* you want to keep your current structure) would be to rewrite this class in Java, or to expose this constructor with a less restrictive visibility (e.g. `internal`.)

There was a [discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/why-outer-class-cannot-see-private-members-of-inner-class/6791/2) about this on the Kotlin forums - it seems that this is a JVM limitation, and that it only works in Java because the compiler generates appropriate `synthetic` accessors.

Comment: OK. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could make make the `constructor` `protected`. This way you only expose it to subclasses, in this case `PrivateClass`. Then you will create an instance of `PrivateClass` or `null` but return it as `InnerClass?`.

```
object InnerFactory {

    fun createInnerObject(startDate: Date? = null, endDate: Date? = null): Inner? {
        // return null here if conditions are not met
        return PrivateClass(startDate, endDate)
    }

    open class Inner protected constructor(val startDate: Date?, val endDate: Date?) {
        fun getTimeDifference(): Long? { /* ... */ }
    }

    private class PrivateClass(startDate: Date?, endDate: Date?): Inner(startDate, endDate)
}
```

Comment: Note that you do not hide that constructor from `Inner` then... you can still call something like `val myFakedInner = object : Inner(null, null) {}` which will then construct a valid `Inner`-object which reuses the functionality you wanted to hide in the first place (if I understood that requirement correctly)... nonetheless depending on the use-case (and if holding that `val`s is ok) that's a valid variant too... you may however want to set the `val`s to `private` at least...

Comment: @Roland sure you can inherit from Inner. I even said that in my answer "This way you only expose it to subclasses...", but you cannot instantiate it directly. That's the weakness of my approach. :D

Comment: true. due to "in this case `PrivateClass`" I just thought I will bring that up so that that isn't misinterpreted..

Comment: @Roland sure, thing :)